# Entity Framework change column delete behaviour without losing data

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Using Entity Framework's automatic migrations I wanted to change the `onDelete` behaviour of a column (a foreign key) but it dropped and created a new column with the same name, hence data in that column would be lost.

My goal is to change the `onDelete` behaviour of a column without loosing data.

Is there a method to change a column's `onDelete` behaviour similar to how `RenameColumn` can be used for changing column name without loosing data or any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please, share the configuration you have used which dropped the table (provide initial config and the modified)